# Two ClosedRanges for DatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, swiftui

Example of date's closed range:

```
var dateClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let today = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -1, to: Date())!
    let seven = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())!
    return today...seven
}
```

Example of time's closed range:

```
var timeClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let min = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 8, of: Date())!
    let max = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 20, of: Date())!
    return min...max
}
```

Example of applying the range:

```
DatePicker(selection: $scheduledStart, in: timeClosedRange) {
    Text("Start Date")
}
```

If I put `dateClosedRange` then I can select a date within the specified days but time can be anywhere between all 24 hours.

If I put `timeClosedRange` then I can select time within 8am-8pm as per the but I can only select current date then and can not select another date.

Any way to put both the ranges in one DatePicker?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DateComponents` instance to achieve that:

```swift
let dateAndTimeRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  let startComponents = DateComponents(
                          year: 2020,
                          month: 1,
                          day: 1,
                          hour: 00,
                          minute: 00,
                          second: 00
  )
  let endComponents = DateComponents(
                        year: 2020,
                        month: 12,
                        day: 31,
                        hour: 23,
                        minute: 59,
                        second: 59
  )
  return calendar.date(from:startComponents)!
    ...
    calendar.date(from:endComponents)!
}()
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to set a date range and a time range on a date picker. The goal is to limit the picker to specific times of the day within a range of days. Your answer simply lets the user pick any date and time during 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two `DatePicker`s using `HStack` and `.labelsHidden()` to create a UI that appears exactly the same as a single `DatePicker`. In the end, you can select the date components from two dates and create a single date output. I hope this helps to solve your query.

**Output of my code:**
[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()
    @State private var selectedTime = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 150) {
            
            Text("Two Dates Pickers combined")
        
            HStack {
                DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, in: dateClosedRange, displayedComponents: .date)  {
                    Text("Start Date")
                }
                
                DatePicker("Select Time", selection: $selectedTime, in: timeClosedRange, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var dateClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let today = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -1, to: Date())!
        let sevenDaysLater = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())!
        return today...sevenDaysLater
    }
    
    var timeClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let minTime = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
        let maxTime = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 20, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
        return minTime...maxTime
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**The UI output of your code is:**

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scheduledStart = Date()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 150) {
            
            Text("Single DatePicker")

            DatePicker(selection: $scheduledStart, in: dateClosedRange) {
                Text("Start Date")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var dateClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let today = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -1, to: Date())!
        let seven = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())!
        return today...seven
    }

    var timeClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let min = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 8, of: Date())!
        let max = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 20, of: Date())!
        return min...max
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```